# error while running the elasticsearch-reindexer from command prompt

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearch-reindex -f http://localhost:9200/artist -t http://localhost:9200/painter

Getting error as:

TypeError: Invalid hosts config. Expected a URL, an array of urls, a host config object, or an array of host config objects.
worker exited with error code: 1
Reindexing completed sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a plugin to do that?

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_reindex?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "index": "artist"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "painter"
  }
}
'
```

This should work just fine. More options and info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/docs-reindex.html).

Comment: I don't want to do it through curl. Can you tell why i'm getting the above error is some syntax error?

Comment: No idea, but the examples here are passing type in addition to index.

https://github.com/garbin/elasticsearch-reindex

`$ elasticsearch-reindex -f http://192.168.1.100:9200/old_index/old_type -t http://10.0.0.1:9200/new_index/new_type`

Comment: I added the type, error has gone. but can't see the changes done to index in elasticHQ.

Comment: But the new index is empty? Yeah, I really can't say, I've always used either curl or the Javascript API.

Comment: new command - elasticsearch-reindex -f http://localhost:9200/artist/artist -t http://localhost:9200/painter/artist. In console Starting reindex in 1 shards.
Reindexing completed sucessfully. It 's working fine. but changes done to index  is not seen in elasticHQ UI. Still index name is the same artist.

Comment: there is no index called painter.

Comment: So you're trying to reindex into a non-existent index? You should create the index first.

Comment: you mean create a new index painter and then run command.But for reindexing we doesn't need to create new index . it will delete the previous and then add new one in place of it.

Comment: No it doesn't man. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

You need to create the new index and do everything else. All the reindex does is copy data.

Comment: ok, I also read that. Thanks I will try now. and update u accordingly.

Comment: I have an total 12 index(entities). I have to reindex every evening. Does it make sense that everyday I will create 12 new index and run the command for each index.

Comment: Why are you doing that?

Comment: for index backup. Is it correct ? I'm not doing it. I'm asking u, whether it is right or wrong?

Comment: For backup functionality, please look into the Snapshot functionality.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html

Comment: if our index gets corrupted.what to do ? taking snapshot will be helpful?.By the way sorry it is not every evening it's once in a week.

Comment: I understood that reindexing will be helpful when you have changes in your database like field so your mapping changes for the index. Is I'm on right track.

Comment: If your index gets corrupted and you have a snapshot, you can drop the index and restore from the snapshot.